# Migracion - crear campo preguntado si no existe en C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, migracion

estoy manejando migraciones en c# con entity v7, queria saber si el codigo que genera la migracion para crear un campo tiene la opcion de preguntar si el campo existe?, para que asi no tenga problemas al ejecutar la migracion, en caso que dicho campo ya exista en la BD.

```
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "Count",
            table: "Movie",
            type: "int",
            nullable: true);
```

Comment: No se, pero bastaría con que hicieras la prueba creo que es el camino más corto para resolver tu duda. Si lo haces recuerda que puedes contestar tu propia pregunta